# is there a equivalent to drawing on a bitmap in js

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, html5-canvas

in C# you can create bitmaps, draw on them, and then you can draw those cached bitmaps.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    surface = new Bitmap(640, 480);
    var g = Graphics.FromImage(surface);
    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, 10, 10, 10, 10);
}
Bitmap surface;

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(surface, 0, 0);
}
```

is there a way to do that in javascript?

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.</canvas>
```

Comment: The question is unclear.  Do you want to draw on a hidden canvas that is not visible on the screen?   And do you need to draw on top of another image or to a blank canvas?

Comment: As mentioned before you changed the code (so it doesn't leak, if you're disposing of the `surface` object at some point), the canvas of a double-buffered Control (any Control used for drawing should be double-buffered) is already a BufferedGraphics object. You don't need a Bitmap when you draw shapes on a canvas. Similar to what you're doing in your JavaScript.

Comment: @Jimi i'm tryng to draw complex shapes, then use they again later transformed on the main canvas with the cost of drawing a image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Canvas is a drawable image.

The function's [CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) first argument is an image or more specifically a [CanvasImageSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasImageSource) which includes the [HTMLCanvasElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement).

### Example

Example draws an arc on `can1` then draws `can1` on `can2` using `drawImage`.

**Note** it draw the pixels, the path is not redrawn on the second canvas.

**Note** The canvas is "double buffered" which means you can also draw the canvas to itself

```js
var ctx1 = can1.getContext("2d");
var ctx2 = can2.getContext("2d");
ctx1.beginPath();
ctx1.arc(64, 64, 60, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx1.stroke();

ctx2.drawImage(can1, 0, 0);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black}
```

```html
<canvas id="can1" width="128" height="128"></canvas>
<canvas id="can2" width="128" height="128"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cache that drawing as png or jpeg base64 string and then you can put it to any image tag or other canvas as well. Here I have cached that image in png data and drawn on an image tag below:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();

var dt = c.toDataURL('image/png');
CANVAS_DATA.src = dt;
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.</canvas>

   <img id="CANVAS_DATA">
```

If you need more info please ask.